# Как делать копию состояния?

Tags: javascript, redux

```
let initialState = {
  questions: [

    {
      name: 'Вопрос 1 ',
      id: 1,
      answers: [
        { name: '1608', isRight: true, id: 1, isSelected: undefined },
        { name: '1871', isRight: false, id: 2, isSelected: undefined },
        { name: '1504', isRight: false, id: 3, isSelected: undefined },
        { name: '1927', isRight: false, id: 4, isSelected: undefined },
      ],
    },

    {
      name: 'Вопрос 2',
      id: 2,
      answers: [
        { name: '1', isRight: false, id: 1, isSelected: undefined },
        { name: '2', isRight: false, id: 2, isSelected: undefined },
        { name: '3', isRight: false, id: 3, isSelected: undefined },
        { name: '4', isRight: true, id: 4, isSelected: undefined },
      ],
    },
  ],
  rightDoneQuestions:0,
}
```

reducer

```
    return {
      ...state,
      questions: state.questions.map((question) => {
        if (question.id === action.questionNumber) {
          return {
            ...question,
            answers: question.answers.map((answer) => {
              if ((answer.id === action.selectedAnswer)) {
                return { ...answer, isSelected: true }
              }
              return { ...answer }
            }),
          }
        }
        return { ...question }
      }),
      rightDoneQuestions : state.questions.forEach((question)=>{
        if(question.id === action.questionNumber){
          question.answers.forEach((answer)=>{
            if(answer.isSelected&&answer.isRight){
              console.log(state.rightDoneQuestions)
              return state.rightDoneQuestions ++
            }
            return state.rightDoneQuestions
          })
        }
      })
    }
```

С помощью reducer я изменяю состояние. Но при изменении примитива rightDoneQuestions возвращается значение undefined. Помогите, пожалуйста, найти ошибку

Comment: state.questions.forEach ничего не возращяет. Импользуйте мап

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понятно  почему у вас forEach имеет return. forEach ничего не возращяет ни при каких условиях.
Но думаю вы должны засенить на find, reduce или map

```
 rightDoneQuestions : state.questions.reduce((acc, question)=>{
    if(question.id === action.questionNumber){
      question.answers.forEach((answer)=>{
        if(answer.isSelected&&answer.isRight){
          acc++;
        }            
      })
    }
    return acc;
  }, state.rightDoneQuestions)
```

Comment: Заменил forEach на map. Тогда возвращается массив со значениями underfined

Comment: Мне не ясна логика данного forEach. Что вы хотели тут сделать?

Comment: Я именно не могу понять логику, как увеличить значение примитива в зависимости от условий, выполняющихся в массиве

Comment: Грубо говоря, в reducer приходит action со свойством questionNumber и selectedAnswer Мы проверяем, если id элемента массива question совпадает с questionNumber, то тогда в этом элементе мы рассматриваем массив answers.Если элемент этого массива имеет id = selectedAnswer, то тогда меняем свойство isSelected у этого элемента. Теперь нам нужно проверить, если свойства isRight и isSelected у этого элемента равны, то нам нужно увеличить на 1 свойство rightDoneQuestions, которое лежит в объекте state.

Comment: Хм дайте переварить

Comment: Так попробуйте.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119489/discussion-between-spleekz-and-aziz-umarov).